# Synchronization block in java

Tags: java, synchronization

```
class Call {
  int count;

  public   void  increment() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
        count++;
  }
}

class Caller implements Runnable {

  Call c;

  public Caller(Call c) {
    this.c = c;
  }

  @Override
  public void run() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        c.increment();
  }
}

class Calling implements Runnable {

  Call c;

  public Calling(Call c) {
    this.c = c;
  }

  @Override
  public void run() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    synchronized (c) {
        c.increment();
    }
  }
}

public class SynchronizedBlock {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    Call call = new Call();
    Calling calling = new Calling(call);
    Caller caller = new Caller(call);

    Thread t1 = new Thread(caller);

    Thread t2 = new Thread(calling);
    t1.start();
    t2.start();
    t1.join();
    t2.join();
    System.out.println("caller:" + caller.c.count);
  }
}
```

Here have made increment method synchronized in 1 class and in other class i havent made it as synchronized. When i run the above code , it sometimes gives value of count less than 2000 .

As per my understanding, Since Calling class's object has already locked the object, so there is no need to synchronize in Caller class increment method.

Could you please help me in understanding the logic here.

Answer (score 1):

> Since Calling class's object has already locked the object, so there
>   is no need to synchronize in Caller class increment method.

Your understanding is incorrect. In order for parallel actions on a variable to be deterministic, you must have some sort of synchronization in place on *every* access/modification to that variable**.

You need to `synchronize` in `Caller` as well.

**: This is a necessary but insufficient condition to guarantee determinism.

Answer (score 1):

`synchronized` keyword in java means that lock will be acquired before entering the block and released after exit.

Since *t2* acquires/releases the lock and *t1* doesn't, there is effectively no synchronization going on. *t1* just goes in the block whenever the CPU time is assigned to it.

*t2* also always goes in the block without waiting because the lock is never acquired by *t1*.

--

If you synchronize the `increment` method your program will work correctly:

```
class Call {
  int count;

  public synchronized void increment() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
        count++;
  }
}
```

After this change you can remove the synchronized block from *t2*.

Comment: here  thread t1 of caller class will first start accessing increment() , after that the synchronization block of thread t2 will take over and lock the object , so what happens to the access of thread t1which was already using increment method.................will tht be put to halt?..........could you please explain that as well

.........and also regarding the CPU time , since the object is locked up by thread t2 , so thread t1 will not be able to access it right?

Comment: You misunderstood the locking part. When t2 holds the lock it doesn't mean that no thread can access the locked object -- it just means that no other thread will be able to lock it again before t2 unlocks it. Since t1 doesn't try to lock it (no synchronized access) it will just use the object without looking at the lock.

Answer (score 0):

What's probably happening when you get the correct value of `2000`, happens between the lines:

```
t1.start();
t2.start();
```

This is because the execution of `public void increment();` is finishing in a single quantum, before the `t2.start()` line is even executed. A [Thread Quantum](http://www.javamex.com/tutorials/threads/thread_scheduling_2.shtml) is the time that the thread runs before a different thread can run on the processors core.

The first thread doesn't lock the object, and occasionally a single quantum will not encompass the entire execution of `increment()`, which leaves time for thread 2 to begin executing and working on the same object data. This will result in 2 copies of the variable `count` existing at the same time, competing for the same memory.

Try increasing the amount of increments `for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)` to some number like  `for (int i = 0; i < 10000000; i++)`. You will most likely see the application begin to fail more often.